# PHP calculate the number of occurance a string is searched from database

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on a project in which i am required to calculate that how much times a user/athlete appears in search results.
Actually there are some coaches who search for athletes. They can search athletes by school/college name, city and state. So i want to calculate that how many times an athlete is searched or appeared in coach searches. 
I have searched internet but unable to find any solution.
This is functionality is implemented on several sites, i.e. on linkedin and on https://new.berecruited.com/search/athletes.
So please help me or give me some guidelines that how i can implement this functionality.

Comment: You should show your current code so we may assist you..

Comment: Post us your codes, database structure

Comment: Welcome to SO. However SO **is not a free coding or analysis service**
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for your time. I have not done any code so far, because i don't know how i can implement it in a best possible way. However, what i am thinking is that, after getting search results, i should do a loop over searched athlete's names and manage a count in a table. But i don't think that my solution is a better way of implementing this functionality. thats why i am asking for guideline.

Answer (score 0):

So you can, on your table, have a column like 'athlete_count', so whenever you retrieve an athlete's names during the search, you also retrive that athlete's ID and athlete_count, and you update your table like this:

```
mysql_query("update athlete_tbl set 'athlete_count' = athlete_count+1 where ID = 'athlete_id' limit 1");
```

Comment: suppose, i get 1000 records in search results then i have to run update query for 1000 times. do you have any better solution.?